# Undefined while retrieving current user data from firestore/firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

If I print current logged in user

```
 console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

Then it prints the user UID.
Then I tried to fetch current user information from firestore doing

```
  import firebase from 'firebase/app'
  import "firebase/auth"
  import db from '../firebase/firebaseInit'

  async getCurrentUser(){
    const database = 
    db.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    const dbResults = await database.get()
    console.log(dbResults.data())
}
```

Then it prints `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.collection("users").where("userId", "==","pass the id you have")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Comment: I hope you understand!

Comment: Yes I still can access these properties you mentioned above but I have stored user information in collection like username, firstName, lastName. So how can I access these properties stored in the firestore.

Comment: First of all you should not store a user info like these because managing it becomes very difficult. If you still want to go with this method ,then you also need to store user id(a unique id provided from firebase) to your collection.

Comment: Now then you can retrieve a user info by following method- Go and check in the answer window I have modified.

Comment: I hope you are understanding my point but If you still have doubts then you are always welcome!

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you set up a user collection in your firestore to store the users? Was the user uid stored in it? Firestore does not do this automatically so if you have not set one up then of course you get no results.
2. Was your db set up properly? Were you able to connect to your db with other methods using current db function?

Also for best practice, its a good idea to rename your database to docRef and dbResult to docSnap instead since it is a reference to a document!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user id stored in the collection as `userId`, you can try:

```
db.collection('users').where('userId', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```